# Dynamically created element doesn't respond to "parent" click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

First and foremost, I know I should use the following code to attach to volatile elements

```
$("#volatiles_container").on("click", ".volatile", function() { ... });
```

I know that.

But it doesn't work, see this demo, the existing works, the created doesn't, why?

http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/607/

see `test1` class and its' event function.

(it's not my page, I found a jsfiddle select2 example on google and added my problem to it)

sorry for the slightly overcomplicated example, just look for `test1`, it's in the html once and twice in the javascript.

**enter 'khglkgliy' in the search**

**EDIT:** this is a simpler example - enter something that's not in the list - http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/614/

Comment: did u notice you have javascript error in the fiddle when ajax call is made and thus blocking the click event after it

Comment: @bipen - maybe, but that isn't the problem (unless I'm missing something, I tried catching all errors and the error you mention is very intermittent), look for something that doesn't return results (ignore all errors). A second "create" link shows up, the existing is clickable and the new one isn't. My codebase (that doesn't throw any errors) also has the same problem

Comment: can you post your example in the fiddle..

Comment: I simplified the example as much as I could - http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/614/

Comment: It's unclear how to get your jsFiddle to do anything.  What are the instructions for reproducing the problem?

Comment: In the HTML portion, there's a Select2-powered dropdown, enter a search (of something that doesn't exist - `asdfasdfh`) and it creates a new link - `create 'asdfasdfh'`. The globally attached click handler for class `test1` doesn't work for the created link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your file select2.js line 682

```
this.dropdown.bind("click mouseup mousedown", function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

I am thinking that the click event is stopped here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue in your jsFiddle (I don't see how to get the jsFiddle to actually create any new objects), but there are these possible reasons that your `.on()` event listener:

```
$("#volatiles_container").on("click", ".volatile", function() { ... });
```

wouldn't work for newly created elements:

1. They aren't children of the `#volatiles_container` object.
2. The newly created objects don't match the selector `".volatile"`.
3. There are other objects on top of the newly created objects that are receiving the click events.
4. Another click handler is stopping event propagation so that the event does not bubble up to the element that has the event handler on it.

Since your event handler is current applied at the top level document, I would guess that it's the 4th item.  I'd suggest using an event handler that is as close to the dynamic element as possible as you can go.

Comment: regarding number 3/4 - it is quite possible since it's a 3rd party library (select2) and not my code that is creating the link - how can I debug that?

Comment: @Madd0g - I'm looking into that now.

Comment: regarding your edit on "getting closer to the dynamic element" - it's the same problem, it's a 3rd party and I can't control where it's in the DOM (it's absolutely floated so it's close to the <body>)